# Django syntax error in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

in my website's main urls.py file, I am trying to add this line:

```
url(r'^account/',include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
```

after adding the line, my file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from invest1.views import *

#to enable admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 'invest1.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'invest1.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'invest1.views.contact_us', name='contact'),

    url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^profile/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles')),
    url(r'^post/', include('posts.urls', namespace='posts')),

    #uncomment to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    #to enable admin
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

no matter what I do to the file, I get the error

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (urls.py, line 18)
```

with the accounts line commented out, the website runs. but no matter where I put the line, it always gives me the same error with the same line number. I've even retyped the whole thing to make sure it's not some illegal whitespace character. I feel like I'm missing something really trivial...what's causing the error?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `accounts.urls`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in one of the other `urls.py` (e.g. `accounts.urls`).